# Why don't LAG( ) and OVER( ) work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, window-functions, lag

I have SQL code below. If I removed `, LAG(myNum, 1) OVER(ORDER BY id)` from the last SQL statement, my code would work. If I keep using `LAG()` and `OVER()` in the last SQL statement, I got error as `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY id) from db001.myTable001' at line 1`. Any ideas how to fix? Thanks!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db001.myTable001;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db001.myTable001
    (id int, myDate VARCHAR(3), myNum int);

INSERT INTO db001.myTable001
    (id, myDate, myNum)
VALUES
    (1, 'Mon', 4),
    (2, 'Tue', 6),
    (3, 'Wed', 3);

SELECT * from db001.myTable001;

SELECT id, myDate, myNum as curNum, LAG(myNum, 1) OVER(ORDER BY id)
from db001.myTable001;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? You need to be running MySQL 8.0 or later to use Windowing Functions like `LAG` and `LEAD`. (There's far too many shops _still running_ MySQL 5.x... I'll bet they're also still running PHP 4 too...)

Comment: Thanks. I am using MySQL57, and now I understand why.

Answer (score 2):

LAG is a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), that is supported by MySQL since version 8.

OVER is just additional syntax that comes with window functions.